# How to convert numpy array into image using PIL?

Tags: image, numpy, save, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

The following code gives me black images and I can't understand why:

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

Code:

```
arr2 = np.zeros((200,200), dtype=int)
arr2[80:120,80:120]=1
im = Image.fromarray(arr2,mode="1")
im.save("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/testImage.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this, using Boolean True and False:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Create black 1-bit array
arr2 = np.full((200,200), False, dtype=bool)

# Set some bits white
arr2[80:120,80:120]=True

im = Image.fromarray(arr2)

im.save('a.png')

print(im)
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=1 size=200x200 at 0x103FF2770>
```

[image]